# Tests working in Selenium WebDriver with PhantomJS

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write a simple test with Selenium WebDriver with PhantomJS to simply log into Reddit, and check if the username is equal to the one displayed on the page. I have the test working when using ChromeDriver, but it seems to not work using the PhantomJSDriver. What is the problem?

Here is a bit of my code:

```
private IWebDriver _driver;

[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    _driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
}

[TestMethod]
public void PhantomLogin()
{
    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(
    "http://reddit.com"
    );

    _driver.FindElement(By.Name("user")).SendKeys("{username}");
    _driver.FindElement(By.Name("passwd")).SendKeys("{password}");
    _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn")).Click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
    By.ClassName("logout")));

    Assert.AreEqual(
      "{username}",
      _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("user")).FindElement(By.TagName("a")).GetAttribute("href").Split('/')[4]
    );
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

**Message: Test method PhantomDemo.UITests.Test.PhantomLogin threw exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL localhost:6114/session/88d4660-6723-11e7-8858-2fa99172/eleme‌​nts timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.**

Edit: added error and more code

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: What do you see if you use a browser to have a look at this address?

Comment: Cannot connect. Sorry, but where is this address coming from? Am I supposed to be hosting a server for WebDriver to be connecting to?

Comment: Please add the error to your question (edit it). Also, Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @wenjay Please post code which initialize PhantomJS driver process and the code which initialize your WebDriver instance.